# Designing unit tests when `Result` is not `Copy`

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns, data-structures, rust, traits

I have a unit test for a container type I'm working on implementing:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_get_mut_normal_tail() -> Result<(), ListError> {
    let mut actual_list: ArrayList<u64> = ArrayList::new();
    let expected_list: ArrayList<u64> = ArrayList {
        elems: vec![1, 2, 3, 8],
    };

    actual_list.append(1)?;
    actual_list.append(2)?;
    actual_list.append(3)?;
    actual_list.append(4)?;

    let actual_res: Result<&mut u64, ListError> = actual_list.get_mut(3);
    let expected_res: Result<&mut u64, ListError> = Ok(&mut 4);

    let elem = actual_res.unwrap();
    *elem *= 2;

    assert_eq!(actual_list, expected_list);
    assert_eq!(actual_res, expected_res);

    Ok(())
}
```

However, `rustc` complains with:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `actual_res`
   --> src\arraylist.rs:358:9
    |
351 |         let actual_res: Result<&mut u64, ListError> = actual_list.get_mut(3);
    |             ---------- move occurs because `actual_res` has type `std::result::Result<&mut u64, list::ListError>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
354 |         let elem = actual_res.unwrap();
    |                    ---------- value moved here
...
358 |         assert_eq!(actual_res, expected_res);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
    = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Which I don't understand, because [the `Result` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-Copy) indicate that `Result` implements `Copy` (provided both of the contained types do also). Clearly `&mut u64` implements `Copy` and my `ListError` type `derive`s it also:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum ListError {
    OutOfBounds,
    Impossible,
}
```

The code for `ArrayList::get_mut()` is here, if relevant:

```rust
fn get_mut(&mut self, pos: usize) -> Result<&mut T, ListError> {
    if pos >= self.elems.len() { /* bounds check */
        return Err(ListError::OutOfBounds);
    }

    match self.elems.get_mut(pos) {
        Some(elem) => Ok(elem),
        None => Err(ListError::OutOfBounds)
    }
}
```

In summary, I have two questions:

1. **How do I fix this error?**
2. **Is there an underlying issue in either my test or my implementation?**

Answer (score 1):

`&mut u64` does not actually implement copy. `&mut T` cannot implement copy to prevent creating multiple simultaneous mutable borrows.

Documentation for reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#trait-implementations

In answer to 1, you can fix the error by using `assert_eq!(elem, 4);` instead of `assert_eq!(actual_res, expected_res);`. Or you could use `Result::map` to modify and return a new result

```
let actual_res: Result<&mut u64, ListError> = actual_list.get_mut(3).map(|elem| {
  *elem *= 2;
  elem
};
```

Comment: The issue with moving the `assert` is that part of what I'm trying to test is that the elements in the list can be manipulated via the `&mut u64` that is returned from `ArrayList::get_mut` (note how `expected_list` is `vec![1, 2, 3, 8]` rather than `vec![1, 2, 3, 4]`, which would match the sequence of `ArrayList::append` calls).

Comment: You're right; I missed that. I can see two ways you can resolve it. You could compare the `elem` value to 4 directly. You could also use the `Result::map` function to modify and return the internal value and get a new result that you could compare to `expected_res`

Comment: So your updated solution fixes the original post's error, but now I'm still faced with the ordering of mutable and immutable borrows (leading me to think my issue is predominantly test design rather than specific syntax).